# Mutt trash not working with imap folder

Tags: mutt

I'm trying to setup mbsync and mutt to work with imap mail (normal imap provided by web hosting company). In my muttrc for this account I have:

```
set trash = "+Trash"
```

But when I try to delete message in mutt I get this notification:

```
Create /home/{user}/.mail/{email-folder}/trash? ([yes]/no)
```

mbsync has synced Trash folder from server. I have even setup mbox_type to Maildir. Why is this happening and how can I force mutt to use Trash folder?

Comment: maybe other settings changes this variable, anyway you can try to see its value when you have open your mailbox with command: `:set ?trash`

Comment: This was very helpful! In my case, I needed to put `set folder` *before* `set trash` in my muttrc

Answer (score 0):

It should work when you set it like this:

```
set trash = "+{email-folder}/Trash"
```

For some reason I don't set the trash variable at all and it works even with multiple accounts. (Each account with it's own Trash.)